# Rails 4 Index only shows 1 user

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise, indexing

I am currently using devise + omniauth authentication to signup users. But when I click on index link, it only shows 1 user. I currently have about 5 demo users signed up. Does anyone know how to show the other 4 users and more that will sign up?

These are my user and controller code lines

```
Application_contoller.rb

class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

    def configure_permitted_parameters
      devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:name, :email, :password, :last_name, :first_name) }
      devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) { |u| u.permit(:first_name, :last_name,:profile_name,:email, :password, :name) }
      devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_in) { |u| u.permit(:name, :email, :password, :last_name, :first_name) }
      devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) { |u| 
      u.permit(:password, :password_confirmation, :current_password, :name) 
    }
    end

end
```

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :authentications
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :omniauthable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,
         :omniauth_providers => [:facebook]

  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :name

  def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_initialize.tap do |user|
      user.provider = auth.provider
      user.uid = auth.uid
      user.name = auth.info.name
      user.email = auth.info.email
      user.oauth_token = auth.credentials.token
      user.oauth_expires_at = Time.at(auth.credentials.expires_at)
      user.save!
    end
  end

  def self.new_with_session(params, session)
    if session["devise.user_attributes"]
      new(session["devise.user_attributes"], without_protection: true ) do |user|
        user.attributes = params
        user.valid?
      end
    else
      super
    end
  end

  def password_required?
    super && provider.blank?
  end

  def email_required?
    super && provider.blank?
  end
end
```

users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def index
    @users = User.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end

  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
      flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  private

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password,
                                   :password_confirmation)
    end
end
```

app/views/user/index.html.erb

```
<% provide(:title, 'All users') %>
<h1>All users</h1>

<%= will_paginate %>

<ul class="users">
  <%= render @users %>
</ul>

<%= will_paginate %>
```

app/views/user/_user.html.erb

```
<li>
    <%= gravatar_for user, size: 50 %>
    <%= link_to user.name, user %>

</li>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: looks like your pagination issue. try <%= will_paginate @users %>

Comment: Are you sure you haven't set WillPaginate's setting `per_page` to "1" somewhere?

Comment: <%= will_paginate @users %> does not seem to work :/ . I haven't touched anything on WillPaginate's settings anywhere so... Any other ideas?

Comment: Maybe a dumb question, but assuming it's not a pagination issue, are you sure the other users are definitely in the target db?

Comment: I don't think that's the case because when I go to rails console and run User.paginate(page: 1), I see all the information there... Thanks for your input though